# How many does 4 have?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, number-property

I found out that

0 has none

1 has one

2 has two

but 3 has none

How many does 4 have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that 4 has...

> ...**two**, if what we are talking about here is **common homophones in the English language**.

To consider the examples:

> 0 ('zero') has no common homophones which are standalone words (the prefix 'xero-' doesn't really count...).
>
>  1 ('one') has a single common homophone: 'WON'.
>
>  2 ('two') has two common homophones: 'TO' and 'TOO'.
>
>  3 ('three') has no common homophones ('free' has a different initial sound).

Thus for 4, we need to consider:

> 'FOR' and 'FORE' - the two common homophones of this word.

Comment: (You can check this answer for yourself by using a source like [this](https://www.rhymezone.com/r/rhyme.cgi?Word=two&typeofrhyme=hom) and looking only at the bold-font results...)